# create dynamic table and show values from datatable with .Append property

Tags: asp.net

I want to show datatable values in my dynamic table,i looped thourough but i couldnt succeeded.dtplants is my datatable.Can you please help me with below code.

```
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<table class=table1>");
        builder.Append("<thead>");
        builder.Append("<th>Configuration</th>");
        builder.Append("<th>Key Figures</th>");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberofplants; i++)
        {
            builder.Append("<th>");
            builder.Append(Convert.ToString(dtplants.Rows[i]));
            builder.Append("</th>");               
        }
        builder.Append("<thead>");
        builder.Append("<table>");

        Literal1.Text = builder.ToString(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must adjust your `end tags` in order to close your table

```
  ....    
  builder.Append("</thead>"); 
  builder.Append("</table>");
```

Your code

```
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.Append("<table class=table1>");
    builder.Append("<thead>");
    builder.Append("<th>Configuration</th>");
    builder.Append("<th>Key Figures</th>");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberofplants; i++)
    {
        builder.Append("<th>");
        builder.Append(Convert.ToString(dtplants.Rows[i]));
        builder.Append("</th>");               
    }
    builder.Append("</thead>");
    builder.Append("</table>");
```

Comment: I did but now the value is System.Data.DataRow.I think i have a trouble with builder.Append(Convert.ToString(dtplants.Rows[i]));

Comment: I'am sorry Asil You can add just data dtplants.Rows[i][j]